# Get max value from one table with the time stamp plus 3 seconds for a time period from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display the `EndTime` with the `TimeStr` value when the `hopper2_setpoint_met` table value is `1`, and I need to display the `Weight` as the `MAX(Value)` from the `hopper2_liveweight` table from the `TimeStr +3 second` starting with the `TimeStr` value when the setpoint met table value is `1`.

**Example Desired Result**

```
+---------------------+--------+
|       EndTime       | Weight | 
+---------------------+--------+
| 2019-06-30 12:02:33 |   300  |
| 2019-06-30 12:04:45 |   299  | 
+---------------------+--------+
```

[image]

---

### The Data and My Attempts

You can access this data from this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa86db) post where I built the schema and inserted a small subset of the data, or if you want to create on your own MySQL database tables with it then here's the SQL for that as well.

```
CREATE TABLE `hopper2_setpoint_met` (
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `hopper2_setpoint_met` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:02:33',1);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_setpoint_met` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:03:51',0);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_setpoint_met` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:45',1);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_setpoint_met` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:05:56',0);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_setpoint_met` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:49',1);

CREATE TABLE `hopper2_liveweight` (
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:02:33',292);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:02:34',298);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:02:35',300);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:02:36',300);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:14',106);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:15',111);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:16',116);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:17',123);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:19',132);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:20',142);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:21',148);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:22',154);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:23',160);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:24',166);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:25',172);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:26',177);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:27',184);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:29',190);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:30',195);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:31',201);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:32',208);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:33',213);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:34',220);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:35',226);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:36',232);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:37',239);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:38',244);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:39',251);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:40',257);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:41',263);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:42',269);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:43',276);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:44',282);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:45',288);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:46',293);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:47',299);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:04:48',299);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:18',108);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:19',112);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:20',117);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:21',123);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:22',128);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:23',135);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:24',141);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:25',148);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:26',154);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:27',160);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:28',165);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:29',172);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:30',177);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:31',183);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:32',190);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:33',196);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:34',201);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:35',208);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:36',213);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:37',220);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:38',226);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:39',231);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:40',237);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:41',242);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:42',248);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:43',254);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:44',262);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:45',269);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:46',276);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:47',282);
INSERT INTO `hopper2_liveweight` (`TimeStr`,`Value`) VALUES ('2019-06-30 12:06:49',288);
```

---

I posted the [MySQL to select max value between on and off time stamps plus 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821968/mysql-to-select-max-value-between-on-and-off-time-stamps-plus-3-seconds) yesterday about something similar for a transporter but I've learned that using the temp table was not the best solution although the answer I received there did give me the expected result I asked for.

I also learned a few things from these answers I received and tried several variations of these things such as the `If(CAST(Value AS UNSIGNED) != 0, Value, Null)  Weight` trick and a few other things for my new task, and again I'm having trouble getting the expected results.

I can certainly get the expected results if I put the data into a temp table but it does not perform well and I believe it over complicates the process as well and is not really needed.

I tried a few different variations using `JOIN` statements and `UNION` data together with sub-queries and fall short when I tried to get the max weight between the timestr+3 second records.

I'd love to learn something new and a light bulb go off in my head from an answer that helps with this problem so moving forward, it's a matter of applying similar logic without needing to create temp or permanent temp tables.

Keeping it all in a query with some `JOIN` statements or even several sub queries if needed would work for me. I wasn't sure if using MySQL session variables would help but I even tried a few things with that and failed.

Comment: Let me know what further I can provide to clarify, etc.

Comment: would it be impossible to simplify your question? (for example, without having to know what are `sensors` and `hoppers`)

Comment: @JaimeDrq Yes, absolutely that is possible. It's one of those damned if you do or damned if you don't things. I was just trying to put some context around it a bit but I'd like to hope with the data, SQLFiddle, SQL, the screen shot, and some of the other noise from the post that people can see from the technical side for the data what I'm trying to do and why. I've also posted SQL in the paste and changed table names to find out I messed something up doing that with something not being valid so it seems best to keep all SQL as-is from this perspective from my experience posting such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One query that fits is:

```
SELECT sm.TimeStr AS EndTime, Max(lw.Value) AS Weight
FROM (SELECT TimeStr FROM hopper2_setpoint_met WHERE Value = 1) sm
INNER JOIN hopper2_liveweight lw ON (sm.TimeStr + INTERVAL 3 SECOND) = lw.TimeStr
GROUP BY sm.TimeStr
;
```

Comment: This is going to work for me. I'll be setting up triggers or a scheduled event to run per each record update from one table or maybe every 15 seconds for a scheduled event with some fail safe logic and an hourly and a 24 hour run job to wrap it up for inserting records into a new table based on this query. I think this will perform best but this logic gives me the exact result I needed. I think joining dates and then add in the +3 seconds and I just struggle with it for some reason. I appreciate your help with this task.